# Launchd starts job over and over again when it is scheduled to run once per day

Tags: mac-osx, launchd

I'm using launchd to run a script that should run once per day.  Instead it runs a number of times (like 40) until it finally stops.  Here is the script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<false/>
<key>Label</key>
<string>emailStats</string>
<key>Program</key>
<string>[redacted]</string>
<key>UserName</key>
<string>[redacted]</string>
<key>ExitTimeOut</key>
<integer>7200</integer>
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>9</integer>
</dict>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>[redacted]</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>[redacted]</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Could  it be that I left out the Minute pair from StartCalendarInterval?

Answer (score 3):

If you leave ou the Minute pair, it runs every minute.